# Error when saving records

Tags: wordpress, error

I get the following error when I save records or when I try to setup the localisation.

[image]

I am using civicrm 5.69.4 for wordpress.

Any help is appreciated.

Talal

Comment: is your site civicrm.settings.php correctly set up to always be using either www or not 'www' or http v https. just sometimes folk end up with systems set up so it has both in different places and it causes them problems

Comment: Hi @petednz-fuzion,

I have tried to edit the civicrm.settings.php file to no avail, tried all options (including www, https etc.)

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: You might find something in the civicrm error log, accessible directly in your filesystem if you have access to it, or via the web interface if you use this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: FWIW, the error you're showing is one of those very unhelpful ones, which is why you want to dig a little deeper to find an error message that preceded what you're seeing on your screen. It might mean an sql-level error, or it might be a file permissions issue, etc. If you do get access to the civicrm error log, then you may have to dig though other noise to figure out which error corresponds to that screen, so keeping track of dates/times can be useful.

Comment: When I installed civivrm, I had the following warning, could this be the reason? @AlanDixon

"It is recommended, though not yet required, to upgrade your PHP MySQL driver (libmysqlclient) to >= 5.5.3 for utf8mb4 support."

Comment: Well, maybe not directly, but that's a flag that your hosting might be the root of your issues, i.e. related your php and/or mysql.